# Why can I change the value of a const char* variable?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

Why does the following code in C work?

```
const char* str = NULL;
str = "test";
str = "test2";
```

Since str is a pointer to a constant character, why are we allowed to assign it different string literals?  Further, how can we protect str from being modified?  It seems like this could be a problem if, for example, we later assigned str to a longer string which ended up writing over another portion of memory.

I should add that in my test, I printed out the memory address of str before and after each of my assignments and it never changed.  So, although str is a pointer to a const char, the memory is actually being modified.  I wondered if perhaps this is a legacy issue with C?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162480/const-in-c

Comment: I'd guess that you were actually printing out the address of the str variable, which doesn't change, its value changes.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are changing the pointer, which is not const (the thing it's pointing to is const).

If you want the pointer itself to be const, the declaration would look like:

```
char * const str = "something";
```

or

```
char const * const str = "something";  // a const pointer to const char
const char * const str = "something";  //    same thing
```

Const pointers to non-const data are usually a less useful construct than pointer-to-const.

Comment: I did a test, however.  I assigned str to a string and printed out the string and it's memory address.  Then, I assigned str to another string and again, printed out the string and it's memory address.  The string literal had changed but the address had not.

Comment: Did you print out the address of the pointer, or the address to which the pointer points?

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Yes, I was printing out the address of the pointer, not the data!  What threw me off in this problem is how C deals with string literals.  You can assign a string literal to a char* but you can't assign an integer to an int* in the same way, for example.

Comment: @Chris: that's because a string literal is actually a char[], which can be implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element

Answer (score 16):

> Further, how can we protect str from being modified?

```
char * const str1; // str1 cannot be modified, but the character pointed to can
const char * str2; // str2 can be modified, but the character pointed to cannot
const char * const str3 // neither str3 nor the character pointed to can be modified.
```

The easiest way to read this is to start from the variable name and read to the left:

- **str1** is a **const**ant **pointer** to a **char**acter
- **str2** is a **pointer** to a **char**acter **const**ant
- **str3** is a **const**ant **pointer** to a **char**acter **const**ant

NOTE: the right-to-left reading does not work in the general case, but for simple declarations it's a simple way to do it. I found a [java applet](http://www.muquit.com/muquit/software/cdcl/cdcl.html) based on code from "The C Programming Language" that can decipher declarations with a full explanation of how to do it.

Comment: Someone could cast away the const if they were really determined, but if the compiler places the chars in a read-only page then modifying them will cause a fault at runtime.

Comment: Technically the compiler and linker together. Switches depend on the tools you're using.

Comment: similar tool for English pointer description: https://cdecl.org/

Answer (score 2):

On a related note, definitely take a look at "[const pointer versus pointer to const](http://blog.voidnish.com/?p=37)". It helps with what some people call *const correctness*. I keep it in my bookmarks so that I can refer to it every now and then.

Comment: That link has moved to here: https://voidnish.wordpress.com/2004/08/01/const-pointer-versus-pointer-to-const/

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for may be the syntax...

```
const char* const str = NULL;
str = "test";
str = "test2";
```

Notice the "const" after the char* which yields a compiler error when trying to compile/build.

Answer (score 1):

Besides, declaring a variable as const means that variable is read-only; it does not mean the value is constant!