# Difference between const char* p and char const* p

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between const int*,  const int * const, int const *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const)

```
    Are there any Difference between const char* p and char const* p
```

Comment: The dupe is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/890535/694576 not where it had been close for, as the latter is about C++.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some of the words are not in the same order.

(there's no semantic difference until the const moves relative to the star)

Comment: I laughed at this more than the SO rules allow me to do.

Answer (score 21):

`const char* p` is a pointer to a `const char`.

`char const* p` is a pointer to a `char const`.

Since `const char` and `char const` is the same, it's the same.

However, consider:

`char * const p` is a `const` pointer to a (non-const) char. I.e. you can change the actual char, but not the pointer pointing to it.

Answer (score 4):

No difference, since the position of the '*' has not moved.

1) const char *p - Pointer to a Constant char  ('p' isn't modifiable but the pointer is)
2) char const *p - Also pointer to a constant Char

However if you had something like:
char * const p - This declares 'p' to be a constant pointer to an char. (Char p is modifiable but the pointer isn't)

Answer (score 2):

There is no functional difference between those two.  The 'more precise' one is `char const * p` because the semantics are right to left.

Answer (score 2):

There's no semantic difference, but it's a matter of coding style and readability. For complex expressions, reading from right to left works fine:

`char const ** const`

is a `const pointer to a pointer to a constant char`.

So `char const *` is more consistent in this regard. Many people, however, prefer `const char*` for its readibility - it is immediately clear what it means.