# constant pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between char s[] and char *s in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

There's a program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[20] = "Hello";
    char *const p=str;
    *p='M';
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints Mello as the answer.. But since p is a constant pointer, shouldn't it give an error?

Comment: read difference between constant pointers and pointer to constants

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a contant pointer, exactly. You can't change **where it points**. You can change **what it points**.

```
const char *p;  // a pointer to const char
char * const p; // a const pointer to char
const char * const p; //combined...
```

The easiest way to memorize the syntax is to not memorize it at all. **Just read the declaration from right to left** :-)

Comment: Perfect answer! :) Made it all clear! :)

Answer (score 2):

`char *const p;` is a constant pointer to a char. So modifying the value pointed by `p` is perfectly legal.

There's a detailed explanation: [const *char vs. char* const vs const *char const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char)

Comment: @Mat, right you are, deleting my comment (even though somebody agreed with me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the value of `p`, but you *can* change the value of `*p`.

If you had written `char const *p=str` or `const char *p=str`, then you would not have been able to modify `*p`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a constant pointer and pointer to constant data. Consider these four:

```
const char * p=str;  // p[0] is const
char const * p=str;  // same
char *const p=str;   // p is const. *p is not
char const *const p=str; // p is const, p[0] also
```