# C : Using char * const pointer

Tags: c, pointers, char, constants

In the following program, p is declared as a pointer(which is constant BUT string is not).But still the program does not work and stops abruptly saying "untitled2.exe has stopped working".

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char * const p = "hello";
    *p = 'm';
    return 0;
}
```

Why this unexpected behaviour?

Comment: This doesn't even look like it should compile.  The first line of `main` is missing a semi-colon, for one.

Comment: "hello" is a literal and stored in static memmory, it can not be modified.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char/890560#890560 remember that, as a rule of the thumb, every time you are using `const` your are triggering some internal actions performed by the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Albeit `p` itself is a pointer to a non-`const` object, it is pointing to a string literal. A string literal is an object which, although not `const`-qualified with regards to its type, is immutable.

In other words, `p` is pointing to an object which is not `const`, but behaves as if it were.

Read more on ANSI/ISO 9899:1990 (C90), section 6.1.4.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting a Windows error because you are invalidly accessing memory. On other systems you might get a SEGFAULT or SEGV or a Bus error.

```
*p = 'm';
```

Is trying to change the first letter of the constant string "hello" from 'h' to 'm';

Comment: DEP is about marking memory nonexecutable. It has nothing to do with marking memory constant or not. (-1)

Answer (score 2):

```
char * const p = "hello";
```

defines a constant pointer `p` and initialises it with the memory address of a constant string `"hello"` which is inherently of type `const char *`. By this assignment you are discarding a `const` qualifier. It's valid C, but will lead to undefined behaviour if you don't know what you are doing.

Mind that `const char *` forbids you to modify the contents of the memory being pointed to, but does not forbid to change the address while `char * const` permits you to modify the contents, but fixes the address. There is also a combo version `const char * const`.

Although this is valid C code, depending on your OS placement and restrictions on `"hello"` it may or may not end up in writable memory. This is left undefined. As a rule on thumb: constant strings are part of the executable program text and are read-only. Thus attempting to write to `*p` gives you a memory permission error `SIGSEGV`.

The correct way is to copy the contents of the string to the stack and work there:

```
char p[] = "hello";
```

Now you can modify `*p` because it is located on the stack which is read/write. If you require the same globally then put it into the global scope.