# Why does the declaration void f (const int *p) is modifying p

Tags: c, pointers, constants

By the declaration

```
const int i;
```

it is clear that `i` cannot be modified.
Then why does the declaration

```
void f (const int *p)
```

is modifying `p`? ( I tested it, it is modifying `p` but don't know how?).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char \* const and const char \*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char)

Comment: Again a wiki link: [Const Correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness#Pointers_and_references)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; The sentence **Thus `const` modifies the name to its right** is confusing on the wiki link(Second para, second line).

Comment: @haccks e.g in `const int *p` right of `const` is `*p`, In expression `int const * const constPtrToConst`  right of first `const` after `int`  is `*constPtrToConst` and right of second `const` is `constPtrToConst`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; How `const` modify name to its right? It should not. As in example your example right of second `const` is `constPtrToConst` and it will not modify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The placement of `const` in a pointer declaration matters. You read it backwards:

- `const int *p` means "p is a pointer to `int` which is constant"
- `int * const p` means "p is a constant pointer to `int`"
- `const int * const p` means "p is a constant pointer to a constant `int`"

Answer (score 3):

Because `const` is `int` pointed to by `p`, not `p` -- the pointer to the `int`.

```
const int *p
```

means that `p` is a pointer to `const int`, `p` can be modified, `*p` not.

The same way

```
int *const p
```

means that `p` cannot be modified, whereas `*p` can.

Note that `const int* p` is the same as `int const* p`.

The simple rule is that the declaration reads from right to the left: `int const *p` means "p is a pointer to constant int", `int *const p` means "p is a constant pointer to an int".

(The actual complete rule is more complicated, you can use http://cdecl.org/ for "decoding" C-style declarations.)

Answer (score 3):

because in this expression, `p` is a pointer to a `const int`. Which means you can change what `p` points to.

This also means that, "p" can itself be modified, but the contents of "p" cannot be modified, so `*p = 10;` will yield error.

An example will clear things:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(const int *p)
{
  int x = 10;
  p = &x; //legally OK
  //  *p = 20; <- Results in an error, cannot assign to a read-only location. 
  printf("%d\n",*p);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const int x10 = 100;
  foo(&x10);
  return 0;
}
```

To make the above program not modify the pointer at all:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(const int *const p)
{
  int x = 10;
  p = &x; //legally NOT OK, ERROR!
  //  *p = 20; <- Results in an error, cannot assign to a read-only location. 
  printf("%d\n",*p);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const int x10 = 100;
  foo(&x10);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving examples.