# strcpy on a string pointer gives errors

Tags: c++

I have read a lot about the subject and I am confused .

What used to work in a `C` file ,not working on a `cpp` file :

```
 char  *builtinFunctions[20];
```

Then I get error on the strcpy function here :

```
void Intepreter::setBuiltIns(char *builtins)
{
   strcpy(builtinFunctions, builtins); // no matching function call to strcpy
}
```

I probably don't understand the basics here, but why in C++ this will not work ( do i need to use **=** instead ? )

```
strcpy(char *, const char*) = thats the structure
```

if I change the  `builtinFunctions` from being a pointer it works.

**EDIT:**
The reason for being a const before this edit is that I read here :
[Why is conversion from string constant to 'char*' valid in C but invalid in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944784/why-is-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-valid-in-c-but-invalid-in-c)

that `char  *builtinFunctions[20];` will produce warning when :

```
builtinFunctions[0]="me";
```

and it did. I could fix it by removing the const .

Comment: This wouldn't work in C either. What's the type of `builtinFunctions`?

Comment: So can you help me understand what am I doing wrong ? ( the const on the variable is needed in c++ compiler otherwise you get a warning)

Comment: @Curnelious I am. Answer the question.

Comment: After my edit, the answer is that its a pointer.

Comment: @Curnelious, after your edit, it's not a pointer. It's an array of pointers.

Comment: @StoryTeller ok , and then ?

Comment: I read here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944784/why-is-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-valid-in-c-but-invalid-in-c that if its not a const you get an error when trying to change it.

Comment: @Curnelious (a) An array of things is not the same as a single thing. (b) You'll get an error in that question even if it is const, since it's pointing to a literal.

Comment: You declare a c-style string as `char builtinFunctions[20];`. But as you are using C++, consider using `std::string`.

Comment: Your edit is very different from the original question.

Comment: I know , I am sorry. I got confused by everything. The edit is just a note. sorry. The reason for using a pointer was because this is an array of words, not characters , so should I use instead something like builtinFunctions[20][10] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an array of pointers to char.

```
char  *builtinFunctions[20];
```

So you call

```
strcpy(builtinFunctions, builtins);
```

gets treated as `strcpy(char **, char*)`, not as `strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)`. So you get a mismatch for first parameter type.

**EDIT:**

So let's suppose `builtinFunctions` is "an array of words" you wish to populate, with `void Intepreter::setBuiltIns(char *builtins)` meant to do just that with it's first parameter being a pointer to a new incoming word. (And you're doing this in a C-style manner. Well, up to you.)

Some things to consider.

1. If you declare an array `type arrName[N];` then the array's name
   being used all alone without index is treated as a variable of type
   `type *arrName`. If you type is initially `char *`, then
   `builtinFunctions` by itself is of type `char**`. That's why your
   `strcpy` fails, but `strcpy(builtinFunctions[someIndex], builtins);`
   works.
2. Before invoking `strcpy` you should consider, if you have a
   destination space allocated. `builtinFunctions[someIndex]` is of
   type `char *`. Where does it point to? Is it a valid pointer to an
   allocated space, or a gateway to hell of undefined behaviour `strcpy`  will happily take you to?

Comment: So how would you copy a new value to this pointer in this function ? should I change it from being a pointer ? it should be an array of words, this is why I used a pointer ( e.g { "aaa","bob",);