# why does GCC give me this `-Wdiscarded-qualifiers` warning?

Tags: c, gcc, constants, typedef, compiler-warnings

In the C SDL project I am working on, I `typedef`ed `char *` to `str` for readability.

Now when I do:

```
const str title = SDL_GetWindowTitle(win);
```

where `SDL_GetWindowTitle` returns a `const char *`, I get:

```
warning: return discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
```

The warning is removeed when I change the type to `char *`:

```
const char *title = SDL_GetWindowTitle(win);
```

A typedef is merely an alias to a type, right? So declaring a variable as `str` or `char *` should be equivalent, why do I get that warning? Or is there something I missed...?

I am using GCC on the CLI, so it's not [an IDE's fault](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44194688/6337519).

Thx in advance!

Comment: "*... on the CLI*"?

Comment: Another nice example why one does not want to typedef pointer-types.

Comment: _"for readability"_ - hard disagree, and this is a great demonstration of why. While you might find it more readable, more experienced users who are used to writing idiomatic code will not, and so I wager that your code will look strange and silly to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`typedef`s are not macro substitution, so in your case

```
const str
const char *
```

are different types.  The former is actually equivalent to:

```
char *const
```

This is a `const` value of `char *` type, so it points to a *mutable* string.  In your example, you cannot modify `title`, but you could modify `*title` through that pointer (if it actually points to non-`const` memory, which depends on what `SDL_GetWindowTitle` does).

You would have to add a separate `typedef` for `const char *` to fix this.

Comment: Huh, I initially typedef'ed `cstr` for `const char *`, but I felt it was unnecessary concision... I guess I'll either put it back or just remove my `str`.