# String literals in structure is showing an error but when string literals declare as a constant it will not show an error why?

Tags: c++, data-structures

This program is compiled and run but showing error:
ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct person{
 char* name;
 char* lastName;
 int age;
};
void show(person temp){
 cout << temp.name << " " << temp.lastName << " age is: " << temp.age;
}
int main(){
// decaring a person    
 person p;
 p.name = "Jayant";
 p.lastName = "Sharma";
 p.age = 18;
//reassigning of p 'name'
 p.name = "Kartik";
 show(p);
 return 0;
}
// output => Kartik age is: 18
```

But when I declare variables using const compiler not shows an error and reassigning is also done

```
struct person{
    const char* name;
    const char* lastName;
    int age;
};
```

reassigning the name 'Kartik' to the same const variable 'name' is done without an error.

Comment: Because `"string literal"` is a `const char *`, and you can't assign a pointer to a const to a pointer to a non-const. C++ does not work this way, that's all. That's what the error message says, in plain words. Which part of the compiler's error message you're unsure about?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik technically, a string literal is a `const char[N]`, which *decays* into a `const char*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your confusion about your sample source code. However, I see two questions you did not explicitly state, but implied. So I will answer both!

### What are String Literals in C++?

The ISO/IEC C++ standard defines a string literal as an array of const char * , and your sample code violates this definition by declaring your variables **name** and **lastName** as having type char * only! Although this isn't the case in the C language see [Why is conversion from string constant to 'char*' valid in C but invalid in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944784/why-is-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-valid-in-c-but-invalid-in-c) for more details!

### Way are Variables Assigned Even When Declared Const?

The compiler doesn't throw an error at you because you did not utilize the const keyword correctly!

```cpp
const char* name = "Sharma";
```

The above code sample states that the **value** held in variable *name* is constant, but its **address** is not!

```cpp
const char* const name = "Sharma";
```

Now the above code sample states that both the **value** and **address** held in variable *name* is constant!

When you use the *member of object* operator you are stating that the memory address being manipulated is the **address** of the object being accessed plus the offset where the data is stored. Therefore, you are **indirectly** modifying your variables via an address!

Comment: Ok I got your point. Address remain same but value isn't. That's what you want to say...

Comment: Was I being to descriptive? If so, sorry about that. I remember asking this same question a long time ago. Finding out that _member of object_ operator returns an __address__ and not an actual __value__ was very surprising time me!

Comment: Not at all your description made it easy for me to conclude about that. So. don't worry about tha.