# Conversion of const char[n] to char*

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm getting this error: "no instance of constructor matches the argument list"
I don't get what am I doing wrong? why can't it convert the "someone" const char[8] to char* (as it is in the constructor) I'd love to get some help, thank you so much!
Constructor:

```
Student::Student(long id, char* name) {
   ...
}
```

Main:

```
Student s1(123456789, "someone");
```

Comment: `Student::Student(long id, char* name)` -- Are you changing `name` in any way in this function?  If you are, be thankful for the error.

Comment: Change the parameter to `const char*`. See [Why is conversion from string constant to 'char*' valid in C but invalid in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944784/why-is-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-valid-in-c-but-invalid-in-c)

Comment: Why not use [std::string](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-stdstring/)? That's the goto datatype for strings since C++11. Using that will make all kinds of things you can do with strings much more easy ( == instead of strcmp, no more calls to strcpy and no more memory leaks).

Comment: `Student s1(123456789, std::strdup("someone"));`  But you should be using `std::string` instead of micro-managing raw owning pointers to C-style C-string arrays.