# Concatenate a char* to a string

Tags: c++, string-concatenation

I have to concatenate all the numbers in a string to another one.

```
char *cif = "1234567890";
char s[100], s1[40] = "", s2[40] = "";
cin.getline(s, 100);

for (int i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
   if (strchr(cif, s[i]))
       strcpy(s1+1, s[i]);
```

But I get:

> error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]|

Comment: *I have to concatenate all the numbers in a string to another one.* -- You tagged this as C++, so why are you not using `std::string`?

Comment: a `char*` is a pointer to a single character. I suppose you want to concatenate the string pointed to by the `char*` with another string, rather than concatenate a pointer with a string. I am picking on words, but confusing the pointer and the pointee is source of most issues beginners have with pointers (and here as well you confuse `char` with `const char*`)

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)` -- You should not be calling `strlen()` in a `for` loop repeatedly like this.  Are you aware of what `strlen()` does, and how it finds the length of the string?  Instead, compute the length once outside the loop, store that in a variable, and use that variable in the `for` loop.

Comment: It looks like your `C` coding is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/erf1zjYvf) using C++.

Comment: [Why is conversion from string constant to 'char*' valid in C but invalid in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944784/why-is-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-valid-in-c-but-invalid-in-c)

Comment: Wrong dupe target. The problem isn't that they try to convert from a string literal to a `char*` (well it is _one_ problem but not the main one), but rather that `s[i]` isn't a pointer by a single `char`. Read the posted compiler message more carefully. (I dupe unhammered the question.)

Comment: You don't use `s2` in your code. You can/should remove it from your [mre].

Comment: Sorry, your code looks bizarre to me. Could you add to your question an explanation of what you intend this code to do, line by line?

Comment: You should indicate where in your code the error occurs. A good way to do this is to copy the full error message into your question, not just the main part. The full error message (for the most common compilers) includes which expression cannot be converted and the location of the error in your code. This is useful information as it reduces guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this the C way in C++ is kind of self-torture since string handling in C is very hands-on and error prone. Someone already posted an example how to better do this using C++.

But if insisting on doing it the C way, you have a bunch of problems here:

- `strcpy` is the wrong way to copy a single character. Just assign it `s1[index] = s[i];`
- `strcpy(s1+1, s[i]);` is a syntax error because `s[i]` is not a pointer, but a single character. This is the reason for your compiler error. But as mentioned above, using `strcpy` was the wrong thing to begin with.
- Rather than using `strchr` on a string of digits, you could use `isdigit` from `<ctype.h>`.
- `char *cif = "1234567890";` is wrong in C and C++ both, because string literals are read-only and therefore a pointer to one should always be `const` qualified no matter language. C++ is stricter than C here since it made string literals type `const char[]`, while they remain `char[]` in C (but are still read-only).
- Calling `i<strlen(s)` inside the loop condition is bad practice, since in theory a bad compiler could call `strlen` repeatedly in that case, leading to bad performance. Very old compilers struggle with this, but modern ones will optimize it. Still, you should avoid placing function calls of any kind there.

Just for completeness, this is what the fixed C code would look like:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void)
{
  char s[100]="1337 something666something lalala 42 ", s1[40] = "";
  size_t s1_count=0;
  size_t length = strlen(s);

  for (size_t i=0; i<length; i++)
  {
    if (isdigit(s[i]))
    {
      s1[s1_count] = s[i];
      s1_count++;
    }
  }
  puts(s1);
}
```

But again, in C++ you should avoid manual string handling like this - use `std::string` (or maybe `std::stringstream`, which is a handy little tool for all your string formatting needs).

Comment: I would even exchange the `strlen` with just checking, whether the current char is 0 and the end is reached.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::string` and its `operator+` to concatenate strings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    const char *cif = "1234567890";
    
    std::string cifs{cif};
    std::string other{"foo"};
    std::string concatenated= other + cifs + other;
    std::cout << concatenated;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4M8cY8q38)

In your code its not actually clear what you want to concatenate with what. I hope the above is clear enough to concatenate any string with any other. Note that non-const pointers to string literals is no longer allowed since C++11 and you need a `const char*`.