# why doesn't the compiler convert character array to my custom-made String class?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, character

I have a custom String class which is not the well-known built-in string class in C++. One of the constructors takes a const character array and looks like the following.

```cpp
String::String(const char* const cString)
{
    itsLen = strlen(cString);
    itsString = new char[itsLen + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < itsLen; i++) {
        itsString[i] = cString[i];
    };
    itsString[itsLen] = '\0';
}
```

Now I have an Employee class that takes 3 character arrays and 1 long, and its implementation looks like this.

```cpp
Employee::Employee(char * fisrtName, char * lastName, char * address, long salary):
    itsFirstName(fisrtName),
    itsLastName(lastName),
    itsAddress(address),
    itsSalary(salary)
{}
```

Quite simple isn't it?

Now my question is, my compiler throws an error when I enter a string or a character array. However, my textbook does not mention of such error and its custom string class works normally.

```cpp
int main() {
    String str = String("testing");
    Employee Yousef("Yousef", "Marey", "123 street", 20000); // error, aren't C-strings already char* ?
    Employee Edie(str, str, str, 500); // error, shouldn't the compiler convert type String into a C-String
}
```

Does anybody know the problem here?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using `char *` in your employee constructor.  C-strings are `const char *` like you using for your string class

Comment: Regarding `error, shouldn't the compiler convert type String into a C-String`.  This is not how `std::string` works.  You have to explicitly call the `c_str()` member to get a `const char *`.  Not sure how you've coded your class though

Comment: Always post complete error along with your question.

Comment: Also as the downvote button suggests, have your tried searching the web? There are plenty of related SO posts. [Why is conversion from string literal to 'char*' valid in C but invalid in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944784/why-is-conversion-from-string-literal-to-char-valid-in-c-but-invalid-in-c)

Comment: `Employee::Employee(char * fisrtName, char * lastName, char * address, long salary)` tells me (and the compiler) that this constructor possibly **modifies** the caller's (dereferenced) arguments for fisrtName, lastName, and address.  `Employee::Employee(char const* fisrtName, char const* lastName, char const* address, long salary)` tells me (and the compiler) that this constructor **does not modify** the caller's arguments for fisrtName, lastName, and address.