# When should I declare an array as static const?

Tags: c, arrays, static, linux-kernel

I came across a warning in Linux system about an array which was declared in usual manner. The warning said that **`static const char * const`** should be used instead of just **`char *`** . Why is that?

How do I know when should an array be declared static constant?

What does `const` after `char *` mean?

Comment: For the warning please show the exact code in question. Both cases are valid in different situations. For the last question you probably should just search SO(e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char)) or the wider web.

Comment: `const` after `char *` means the pointer itself is `const`.  Whether it's appropriate to use `static` and/or `const` in general depends on the context.

Comment: use 'const' modifier when the array will never change.  use 'static' to 1) remove the array from the stack 2) to make the invisible to other files