# Searching const key type in set causes compile error

Tags: c++, c++11, set, g++, c++14

I have a `set` of a pointer type but searching using a const pointer is impossible, my code is such as below:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
  string name;
  int id;

  Node(const string &name, int id):
    name(name),
    id(id)
  {}
};

struct Comprator
{
  bool operator()(const Node* lhs, const Node* rhs) const
  {
    return lhs->id < rhs->id;
  }
};

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  set<Node*, Comprator> d;

  Node* node3 = new Node("foo", 4);

  d.insert(node3);

  const Node* node4 = node3;

  auto it = d.find(node4);

  return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
main.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cc:38:25: error: invalid conversion from ‘const Node*’ to ‘std::set<Node*, Comprator>::key_type {aka Node*}’ [-fpermissive]
   auto it = d.find(node4);
                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/set:61:0,
                 from main.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_set.h:694:7: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::find(const key_type&) [with _Key = Node*; _Compare = Comprator; _Alloc = std::allocator<Node*>; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<Node*>; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = Node*]’
       find(const key_type& __x)
```

If I change `Node*` to `int` every thing works, I do not understand the problem. I use c++11 and g++-5.4.0.

**Edit:**

As @Piotr Skotnicki explained in the comments in c++14 the below code for comparator could compile:

```
struct Comprator
{
  using is_transparent = void;

  bool operator()(const Node* lhs, const Node* rhs) const
  {
    return lhs->id < rhs->id;
  }
};
```

Comment: You can add `using is_transparent = void;` to the declaration of your `Comprator`

Comment: I added the statement to my comparator class but nothing has changed.

Comment: You'd need to use the `-std=c++14` mode flag

Comment: Yes, It works, thanks for your help. Please give me a link to find the reason why this works in c++14 if there is any.

Comment: It's a [c++14 feature](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20317413/3953764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const Node*` (a non-const pointer to `const Node`) is not const key - that would be `Node* const` (a const pointer to `Node`).

Either change your `set` to be a set of `Node const*`, or pass pointer to non-const `Node`s to it.

Here's a more in-depth explanation: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char)

Comment: Yes this is true, I have forgotten the difference between `const Node*` and `Node* const`

Comment: Do you think that using `const_cast` is appropriate here? Because in general I think `const_cast` is an evil, but in the other side it must be possible to use const of a pointer to query from the set.

Comment: @MohsenTamiz It will be safe, since you won't access the element during the `find` operation. But it smells like a design problem, you're correct