# Compiler ignores 'const' on function parameter

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, gcc

I have a problem with a compiler error, take a look at this code:

```
template<class T>
struct MyStruct
{
};

template<>
struct MyStruct<int>
{
    typedef int* type;
};

template<class T>
void foo(const typename MyStruct<T>::type myType)
{
}

int main()
{
    const int* ptr = NULL;
    foo<int>(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the compiler is ignoring the 'const' on foo function, making the call to foo illegal (const int* to int*).

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2664   'void foo(const MyStruct::type)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const int *' to 'const MyStruct::type'

I have tested the following code in Visual studio's and gcc's 5.3 complier, both of them dropping the same error.

Does the complier doing this on purpose? why is this happening?

Comment: `const int* ptr` is not a const pointer, it is a pointer to const.

Answer (score 8):

There is an important distinction between `const int *` and `int * const`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/890560/7359094) for an explanation of the difference.

Consider what `const typename MyStruct<T>::type` means. It's a `MyStruct<T>::type` that is `const`. In this case, it's an `int*` that is `const`. This is a `int* const`, a pointer which can't be reassigned a new address but that can still be used to modify the pointed `int`. However, the pointer you are passing in `foo<int>(ptr)` is a `const int *` which cannot be converted to `int * const`, as it would be discarding the `const` qualifier.

To achieve what you want, `const` must be part of the type before making it a pointer. It can't be added after the fact or it will always be interpreted as `T * const`. You can use type traits to remove the pointer part of the type, add const and then make it a pointer.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct MyStruct { };

template<>
struct MyStruct<int> {
    typedef int* type;
};

template<class T>
void foo( std::add_const_t<std::remove_pointer_t<typename MyStruct<T>::type>> * myType) {}

int main()
{
    const int* ptr = nullptr;
    foo<int>(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```