# explicit specialization of template

Tags: c++, c++11

This is my function template

```
template<class T> const T& min(const T& a, const T& b) {
return (a < b) ? a : b;
}
```

The sole purpose of function is to return min of two argument. The arguments are read only..

Here is explicit specialization for char* arguments

```
//Code 1:
    template<>
    const char*& min<const char*>(const char* &a,
    const char* &b) {
    return (strcmp(a, b) < 0) ? a : b;
    }
```

Even though having read only argument this code gives an error. Although code below works perfectly

```
//Code 2:    
template<>
    const char* const& min<const char*>(const char* const& a,
    const char* const& b) {
    return (strcmp(a, b) < 0) ? a : b;
    }
```

Why do i have to provide **const&** after **char*** if **&** or **const** alone is enough for making argument read only. What is the meaning of **const&** in  Code 2..??

EDITED:

I am getting this error code while compiling with Code 1..

```
error: template-id 'min<const char*>' for 'const char* const& min(const char*&, const char*&)' does not match any template declaration|
```

while there is no error code with compiling with Code 2..

Comment: Look here (c, but the answer is valid here): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char

Comment: Eeerm you declared your template params as a reference (`T&`). So why do you wonder you have to keep it like that in the specialization? Can you elaborate about your doubts please?

Comment: Yes but why to use const& when u can use either 'const' or 'reference operator (&)' alone to make sure that pointer always point to the same address...

Comment: @abhi_awake _"or 'reference operator (&)' alone"_ Huh, what??

Comment: What i want to say is **const char* &a** or **const char* const a** says that a is read only i.e it points to same address and its content doesn't change but what does **const char* const& a** means.... Why here we have used both **const+reference operator (const&)** ???

Comment: `const char* &` is a non-const reference to `const char*`, not a const reference to `char*`. It is not a specialisation of `const T&`. (And you're using different types for the return value and the parameters.)

Comment: thnkz @molbdnilo.... I got what was wrong...

Answer (score 2):

In your first declaration

```
template<class T> const T& min(const T& a, const T& b) {...}
```

`const T&` is actually equivalent to `T const &`, i.e., a reference to a constant `T`. If you want to specialize that function, it still needs to get a reference to a constant *something*. If you want to specialize for `const char*` (which is the same as `char const *`, i.e., a pointer to a constant `char`) you thus need to write: `char const * const &`, i.e., a reference to a constant pointer to a constant `char`.

Generally, `const` always refers to whatever is written to its left, only if `const` itself is at the very beginning, it refers to whatever is written to its right.

**Addendum** (off-topic, this does not explain the actual problem):

Instead of template specialization, you could just overload `min`:

```
const char* min(const char* a, const char* b) {
    return (strcmp(a, b) < 0) ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: @abhi_awake Proper english please. Even in comments.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry, for any inconvenience caused

Answer (score 1):

You actually have 2 different specializations for `char*`.

The signature of the 1st one

```
const char* const& min<const char*>(const char* &a,
const char* &b)
```

makes the value pointed to read only. While the 2nd one

```
const char* const& min<const char*>(const char* const& a,
const char* const& b)
```

also makes the pointer parameters being read only.
The 1st signature would allow to change the pointers passed as parameters from inside the function.

Comment: compiler is giving error on first code... That is what is confusing.. Why can't we use first code

Comment: @abhi_awake Please put the verbatim error message into your question. It's probably because your 1st signature usues a different type as return type than specified in the template.

Comment: error: template-id 'min<const char*>' for 'const char* const& min(const char*&, const char*&)' does not match any template declaration

Comment: @abhi_awake I said [_put it into your question_](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44472207/edit)!