# modify const char * vs char * content in easy way

Tags: c++, char, constants

im realy confused about `const char *` and `char *`.
I know in `char *` when we want to modify the content, we need to do something like this

```
const char * temp = "Hello world";
char * str = new char[strlen(temp) + 1];
memcpy(str, temp, strlen(temp));
str[strlen(temp) + 1] = '\0';
```

and if we want to use something like this

```
char * str = "xxx";
char * str2 = "xts";
str = str2;
```

we get compiler warning. it's ok I know when i want to change `char *` I have to use something memory copy. but about `const char *` im realy confused. in `const char *` I can use this

```
const char * str = "Hello";
const char * str2 = "World";
str = str2; // and now str is Hello
```

and I have no compiler error ! why ? why we use memory copy when is not const and in const we only use equal operator ! and done !... how possible? **is it ok to just use equal in const? no problem happen later?**

Comment: What specific compiler warning did you get when you did `char * str = "xxx";
char * str2 = "xts";
str = str2;`?

Comment: this may help a bit:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char the pointer is NOT constant so you can change what it points to but the value it points to is constant so you cannot change it.

Comment: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

Comment: Be careful to distinguish between a **pointer** and **what it points at**. Modifying the contents of a `char*` is simple: just assign a new value to it. This question is about modifying the contents of an array that a pointer points at, and that's a rather different subject.

Comment: Beware that `str = str2` is changing *which* string `str` points to, it does not modify the value of the string it is pointing to in any way.

Comment: What if you try `str[5]='!'` on the const char version?

Comment: Don't use `memcpy` here. Use `strcpy`.

Comment: Use std::string.

Comment: You don't do either of these in C++. Not sure where you learnt this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is cause your variables are just a pointers `*`. You're not modifiying their contents, but where they are pointing to.

```
char * a = "asd";
char * b = "qwe";
a = b;
```

now you threw away the contents of a. Now a and b points to the same place. If you modify one, both are modified.

In other words. **Pointers are never constants** (mostly). your `const` predicate in a pointer variable does not means nothing to the pointer.

The real difference is that the pointer (that is not `const`) is pointing to a `const` variable. and when you change the pointer it will be point to ANOTHER NEW `const` variable. That is why `const` has no effect on simple pointers.

Note: You can achieve different behaviours with pointers and const with more complex scenario. But with simple as it, it mostly has no effect.

Comment: so you say when we create a new char *, a char type create in the memory and this char * point to that char storage, and when we set two char * equal, both points to that type but if you say this why when i set this code and i want to print b i get qwe content ??????

Comment: Yes. when you do `a = b` both of them are pointing to the same `"qwe"` memory. Correcting your comment " and when we set two char * equal, both points to the SAME PLACE"

Comment: "**Pointers are never constants**" and "`const` has no effect on pointers" is an exaggeration. A constant pointer (`char* const str = "Hello"`) is sometimes useful.

Comment: Yes I agree... I will add a note on the answer.

Comment: _"Pointers are never constants"_ `this` disagrees

Comment: Well remembered.

Answer (score 1):

This is a confusing hangover from the days of early C. Early C didn't have const, so string literals were "char *". They remained char * to avoid breaking old code, but they became non-modifiable, so const char * in all but name. So modern C++ either warns or gives an error (to be strictly conforming) when the const is omitted.

Your memcpy missed the trailing nul byte, incidentally. Use strcpy() to copy a string, that's the right function with the right name. You can create a string in read/write memory by use of the

```
char rwstring[] = "I am writeable";
```

syntax.

Comment: String literals were **array of `char`** and now they're **array of `const char`**.

Comment: No, modern C++ prevents compilation when the `const` is omitted. It has been mandatory for over half a decade.

Comment: My compiler (XCode) is up to date and still warns, but edit made to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers say, you should distinguish pointers and bytes they point to.

Both types of pointers, `char *` and `const char *`, can be changed, that is, "redirected" to point to different bytes. However, if you want to change the bytes (characters) of the strings, you cannot use `const char *`.

So, if you have string literals "Hello" and "World" in your program, you can assign them to pointers, and printing the pointer will print the corresponding literal. However, to do anything non-trivial (e.g. change `Hello` to `HELLO`), you will need non-`const` pointers.

Another example: with some pointer manipulation, you can remove leading bytes from a string literal:

```
const char* str = "Hello";
std::cout << str; // Hello
str = str + 2;
std::cout << str; // llo
```

However, if you want to extract a substring, or do any other transformation on a string, you should reallocate it, and for that you need a non-`const` pointer.

---

BTW since you are using C++, you can use `std::string`, which makes it easier to work with strings. It reallocates strings without your intervention:

```
#include <string>
std::string str("Hello");
str = str.substr(1, 3);
std::cout << str; // ell
```

Answer (score 0):

Citing Malcolm McLean:

> This is a confusing hangover from the days of early C. Early C didn't have const, so string literals were "char *". They remained char * to avoid breaking old code, but they became non-modifiable, so const char * in all but name.

Actually, string literals are not pointers, but arrays, this is why `sizeof("hello world")` works as a charm (yields 12, the terminating null character is included, in contrast to strlen...). Apart from this small detail, above statement is correct for good old **C** even in these days.

In **C++**, though, string literals have been arrays of constant characters (`char const[]`) right from the start:

C++ standard, 5.13.5.8:

> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type **“array of n const char”**, where n is the size of the string as defined below, and has static storage duration.

(Emphasised by me.) In general, you are not allowed to assign pointer to const to pointer to non-const:

```
char const* s = "hello";
char ss = s;
```

This will fail to compile. Assigning string literals to pointer to non-const *should* normally fail, too, as the standard explicitly states in C.1.1, subclause 5.13.5:

> Change: String literals made const.
>   The type of a string literal is changed from “array of char” to “array of const char”.
>   [...]
>
> ```
> char* p = "abc"; // valid in C, invalid in C++
> ```

Still, string literal assignement to pointer to non-const is commonly accepted by compilers (as an extension!), probably to retain compatibility to C. As this is, according to the standard, invalid, the compiler yields a warning, at least...