# What is defined here as const (char** and ie.)?

Tags: c++, constants

given variable that define as `char** const var;` , what is defined here as const (var or *var) ?

And in the general case, how can I know it? (namely, given it: `char**** const var` , what is defined here as const?)

Comment: `var` is a constant pointer to a pointer to a `char`. It's the first-level pointer that is constant. Once you assign to `var` you can no longer reassign it. The amount of "stars" doesn't matter, it's the order of the `const` qualifier that is important.

Comment: Not sure about the duplicate, although the answer might be the same, OP seems more interested in the amount of `****`s.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/890595/4402721) to the linked duplicate gives the rule for what is const.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read right-to-left. The const refers to what is to the left. The exception is that a declaration may start with const, in which case it refers to the thing on the right.

`char const * const` is a constant pointer to a constant char. So `char ** const` is a constant pointer to a pointer-to-char.