# difference between `using` and plugging in directly

Tags: c++, constants, using

Consider the 2 snippets:

```
using x = int*;

int main () {
  const x a = new int(3);
  *a = 5;
}
```

and

```
int main () {
  const int* a = new int(3);
  *a = 5;
}
```

The first compiles, while the second doesn't

--> `using` is not equivalent to simply "plugging in" the type and then parse the line.

Are there more differences between using `using` and "inlining" the type directly?

Comment: What is `const` in each? Can you tell?

Comment: The former declares a constant pointer to non-const data; the latter declares a non-const pointer to constant data. Naturally the latter won't work with `*a = ...`. It's all about where `const` attaches itself. There are probably a hundred dupes of this question. Time permitting, I'll try and hunt some down. Fyi, this isn't unique to `using`. Set it up with `typedef` as well.

Comment: first: the pointer is const; second: the int

Comment: Exactly! So what surprises you?

Comment: @FredLarson at all, OP did not express surprise with the outcome. Instead, the question is **Are there more differences between using using and "inlining" the type directly?** Any dup closure with the question which would ask 'why the behavior is different' would be incorrect.

Comment: i was aware of that, and i think it makes sense that it is like that. But in my (admittedly short) path of learning c++, i never saw a difference between plugging the type in directly and typedef'ing it. and i just wondered if this is the only case where it  makes a difference

Comment: @WhozCraig this is not the question OP asks.

Comment: @kawillzocken I'm confused then. You seem to be asking if two different things have any "more differences" (and that probably isn't accurate either). Wasn't one enough? The subtlety of hiding a pointer-to-type in an effective type alias will often rear things like this, which is one reason it is typically *discouraged*. Is your question whether there are any *other* reasons besides the one you've shown?

Comment: @WhozCraig i was simply wondering about additional differences and examples where those are relevant

Comment: Using `volatile` will have the same difference, I think. I am not certain since it's something I rarely, if ever, use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference in interpretation is due to the way C++ declarations deal with pointer const-ness, which borrows its semantics from C. Basically, `const int* x` and `int * const x` mean different things, [as explained in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/890535/335858).

In turn, this interpretation is due to the way the "anonymous" pointer types are derived syntactically: language designers decided to assigning const-ness to the pointed-to value, not the pointer itself, when `const` is at the front of the declaration.

Note that the same thing happens when you `typedef` a pointer type:

```
typedef int* x;

int main () {
    const x a = new int(3);
    *a = 5; // Works fine
    return 0;
}
```

Essentially, adding a `using` or `typedef` makes C++ treat `int*` as a single type, with only one way of assigning const-ness. On the other hand, writing `int*` directly is treated as a "derived" pointer type, which is governed by a different set of rules.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question as asked.

Comment: @SergeyA My hope here is that once OP understands where this difference is coming from, he'd have no problem figuring out the "are there more differences" question on a case-by-case basis. In a way, this is a fish-vs-fishing-rod situation: once you explain the root cause, all the specifics become obvious.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the east-const (const on the right) / west-const (const is on the left) issue.

`const`on the left is only allowed only in one place: in the beginning of a type declaration. The rule is `const` is on the right to the type which it applies. And when it is written on the left, it is the same as been on the right of it's type.

So:

```
const int i1;

int const i2;
```

Is the same. (constant int)

And:

```
const int* i3;

int const* i4;
```

Is the same. (a pointer to constant int)

But with `using` we have a different situation.

```
 const X i5;

 X const i6;
```

Are the same.

So when we substitute for X the type we get:

```
 int * const i6;
```

Which is a constant pointer to a (non-constant) int.

This is what you have to look out for.