# Error :Argument of type 'const char*' is incompatible with parameter of type 'char*'

Tags: visual-c++

What does this error mean and how can I solve it?
"argument of type 'const char*' is incompatible with parameter of type  char*'"

I have this C++ method defined as:

```
void output(int x, int y, char*string)
```

and I'm trying to call it like this:

```
output(-11, 6, "Top");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char \* const and const char \*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char)

Answer (score 0):

"Top" is a constant. The compiler sees the characters and understands this is not a modifiable data.

Your output method demands a pointer to a char array. This means to a pint in memory where there is a string of varying length.
To accomplish what you need to do try this:

```cpp
      char cstr[10];
      strcpy(cstr,"Top");
      output(-11,6,cstr);
```