# member pointer to const

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to implement the rule of five using the swap idiom.

however, i have internal member fields that are const.

I tried at first to make const_cast, but as I see it probably impossible in this case.

I got into conclusion that the best way will be to turn the member field into ptr to const.

I tried to do this via the initalization list, but cannot find the right syntax. 
the following doesn't compile:

```
HashMap<KEY, VALUE>::HashMap(double threshold)
: *_thresholdPtr(threshold)
```

...

```
const double * _thresholdPtr;
```

I will be grateful to your help, first if ptrs to const are the best way in this case, 
and how to do it if yes.

thanks!

EDIT: I know that const double* is not like double * const. 
      but what I'm trying to do is to recieve a double number, and
      attach it as a const double to a pointer which is not const 
      (in order to be able to use the swap)

Comment: Either the class members cannot be `const`, or moving/assigning the objects does not move/assign these members. Those are your options.

Comment: **Obviously** if your field are `const`, they cannot be modified as it is the whole purpose of making an object `const`. By the way, `const_cast` should rarely be used. You should almost always fix the constness at the source and make any necessary change in the whole chain.

Comment: And you should always format your code in a question. Unformatted code is harder to read. By putting some effort in writing your question, you increase the chance that people might help you. Also showing all required code won't hurt.

Comment: It's not clear what you want here. You created a class member variable that is a pointer. What exactly do you want it to point to?

Comment: If  `_thresholdPtr` is a pointer, you must first make it actually point somewhere before you can dereference it. In the code you show you don't make it point anywhere. Why do you have it be a pointer in the first place? What problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: @NissimLevy `HashMap<KEY, VALUE>::HashMap(double threshold): *_thresholdPtr(threshold)` What does this means? Or what were you trying to say? What did you actually want? Perhaps you meant to write to `HashMap<KEY, VALUE>::HashMap(const double* thresholdPtr)
: _thresholdPtr(thresholdPtr)`?

Comment: Note that `const doublt *_thresholdPtr` is NOT const -- it is a NON CONST pointer to a const double.  So there's no problem with changing the pointer in the swap or assignment or wherever.

Answer (score 0):

The order where your `const` declaration happens in relation to the data type matters when declaring pointers. `const double *_thresholdPtr;` creates a double that can be pointed to, but itself cannot be changed. `double *const _thresholdPtr;` creates a constant pointer to an existing `double`.

I'm not sure if it will help, but I ran into a similar issue with some code. [This post helped me understand the difference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char)

EDIT: As comment below, the difference is where pointer is declared.

Comment: `double *const foo:` is a const pointer to non-const double, the two you mentioned are equivalent.