# Modifying a const pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, const-pointer

I am trying to understand why the following code compiles and runs fine. I would expect any assignment using `data` inside `f` not to compile with a gcc error `assignment of member ‘i’ in read-only object`. Is there some kind of exception, because `data.i` is allocated dynamically?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct a {
    int *i;
};

void f(const struct a *data) {
    data->i[0] = 55; 
}

int main() {
    struct a data;
    data.i = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    
    f(&data);
    
    printf("%d\n", data.i[0]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not modifying the pointer but something it points, so there is no problem with this code.

Comment: You would get an error if you tried to modify `data->i`, but modifying `data->i[0]` does not change the contents of `data`.  If `i` were an array rather than a pointer, then the situation would be different.

Comment: @tom-karzes Is there a way to forbid any assignment to a memory location accessed by `data` pointer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char

Comment: @b1000 You'd need to change the declaration of `i` within the `struct`.

Comment: @b1000 You could declare it as `const int* i;` inside the struct but then you can no longer use malloc, so that would be quite useless in this case.

Comment: Inside `f()` the following applies:`data` is not const; `data->i` is const; `data->i[0]` is not const

Answer (score 2):

`const` front of a `struct` will make it read-only. If the struct contains pointer members, then those pointers themselves will turn read-only. Not what they point at.

That is, `const struct a` will make the member `i` behave is if it was declared as `int *const i;`, meaning that the pointer itself cannot be changed to point elsewhere. The pointed-at data is still of read/write `int` though.

If you want to restrict access to `i` inside a function, you should make that function take a `const int*` parameter and pass the `i` member to that function.

Answer (score 1):

In the below code, `const` indicates what `data` points to is not to be modified.  `data->i[0] = 55;` does not modify the pointer `data->i`.  Instead that line of code modifies the memory pointed to by `data->i`. This is allowed as pointer `.i` is `int *` and not `const int *`.

```
struct a {
    int *i;
};

void f(const struct a *data) {
    data->i[0] = 55; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant modify `i` but you can modify the objects referenced by `i`.

To prevent it you need to:

```
struct a {
    const int *i;
};
```