# Can someone explain what is happening on line 3?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

```
vector<long> v = {1,2,3};
long i = v.size();
const long* w = (i != 0) ? &v.front() : NULL;
```

Can someone explain what is happening on line 3? To me, it feels like v = w. Am I understanding it right?

Comment: Is it [ternary operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) which looks strange for you?

Comment: you can reconstruct that as `if (i != 0) w = &v.front(); else w = NULL;`

Comment: read the reference by Jarod42 or this http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1AUq5Di1/ and you will understand what it means

Comment: Just to be pedantic: `long i = v.size()` would be better as `size_t i = v.size()` and, in C++, you should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Yes, the right hand side confuses me. @Jarod42

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you! @zois

Comment: Thank you! @AndreyChernukha

Answer (score 4):

`e1 ? v1 : v2`

That's `?:` expression where when expression (`e1`) has true, it returns `v1`, else returns `v2`.

Here it means point constant pointer (cannot change address once assigned address) to `NULL` if `v` has no value inside. Or the first element's address if `v` has at least one element inside.

Comment: It's a pointer to a long that is const, meaning you cannot change the pointed-to value, but can indeed change where the pointer points. The ternary operator is not just the ?, but is `?:`.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

> it feels like v = w.

No, not at all. `v` is a `std::vector<long>` (assuming `vector` is `std::vector`) and `w` is a `const long*`. Thats two completely unrelated types. You cannot assign one to the other.

Actually your code is similar to:

```
vector<long> v = {1,2,3};
const long* w = &v[0];
```

`w` is a pointer to the first element in the vector. `v.front` is just a different way to get a reference to the first element. And because in general we cannot know if `v` has an element at index `0`, the author added a check:

```
vector<long> v = {1,2,3};
long i = v.size();
const long* w;
if ( v.size() != 0) w = &v.front();
else                w = nullptr;
```

And a less verbose way of writing the same is using the conditional operator:

```
const long* w = ( v.size() != 0 ) ? &v.front() : nullptr;
```

Depending on the condition, only one side of `:` is evaluated, hence out-of-bounds access to element `0` in an empty vector can be avoided.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

"const long* w = (i != 0) ? &v.front() : NULL; " It checks whether vector has elements. If vector has elements, it assigns first elements address to long type pointer. ? is ternary operator. example int a=1;int b=2; (a<b)? "if true do something" : "if false do something" ;

Answer (score 1):

`const long* w = (i != 0) ? &v.front() : NULL;`

`w` is a pointer to a `long` constant - [not to be confused with a `const` pointer to a `long`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char). The value of the pointer is being initialized to the result of the ternary expression: `(i != 0) ? &v.front() : NULL;`

---

> The ?: operator returns one of two values depending on the result of
> an expression.

Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1AUq5Di1/

---

If `(i != 0)` is true then the result will be the [address of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/addressof/) the reference returned by [`v.front()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/front/) (i.e.: the first element in the vector `v`). If the expression evaluates false then `w` will be a null pointer.

A good rule to follow to ensure you understand any declaration properly is [The "Clockwise/Spiral Rule"](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) - understanding this rule can save you some headaches.