# Error : invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, constants, syntax-error

> first of all this is not duplicate one because same error Question
> asked before but in different context

#### 1

**code**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

int main()
{
    const char *s1;
    const char *s2="bonapart";
    
    s1=new char[strlen(s2)+1];
    strcpy(s1,s2);
    
    std::cout<<s1;
}
```

**Output**

```
[Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
```

**Why such error ?**

If I replace `const char *s1` by `char *s1`  compile fine. But I think this `const` only saying that s1 is pointing to **constant string** means we can't modify that string whom it is pointing. It does not mean that `s1` is **constant ptr**. please put some light on this.

Comment: Do you think `strcpy(s1,s2);` would not modify the target string?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char

Comment: @HansPassant https://stackoverflow.com/q/67772282/11862989 can you answer this question please .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why such error ?

Look at the declaration of `strcpy`:

> ```
> char* strcpy( char* dest, const char* src );
> ```

Pay particular attention to the first parameter. And very particular attention to the type of the first parameter: `char*`. It isn't `const char*`.

Now, look at the type of the argument that you pass.

> ```
> const char *s1;
> ```

It's not `char*`. It's `const char*`. You cannot pass a `const char*` into a function that accepts `char*` because former is not convertible to the latter, as the diagnostic message explains.

> But I think this const only saying that s1 is pointing to constant string means we can't modify that string whom it is pointing.

That's exactly what `const bchar*` means. So, how do you expect `strcpy` to modify the content of the pointed string when you know that it cannot be modified? <sub>Technically in this case the pointed string isn't const, it's just pointed by a pointer-to-const</sub>

Comment: `So, how do you expect strcpy to modify the content of the pointed string when you know that it cannot be modified?` ohh  I get it so that's the reason why the first parameter of `strcpy` declaration is `char*` not `const char*` right ? and Thanks

Comment: @AbhishekMane Well, yes. The function copies the string from the right argument to the left argument.

Comment: can you help me. I Just started job after graduation and I have work on CPP REST SDK Library. I have to do that task in very short period of time. If you teach me for one hour it will great help. I will pay your charges. I don't know how to connect with you so commenting here. Please I really need your help

Answer (score 2):

As you say, `const char *s1;` means that the string pointed at by `s1` is not modifyable.

On the other hand, `strcpy(s1,s2);` will modify the string pointed at by `s1`.

This is against the condition "the string pointed at by `s1` is not modifyable".