# arguments a constant in template function

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I have a template function as below which has one of the arguments a constant

```
template<typename T>
T maxAmong( T x, const T y) {
    return x ;
}
```

For explicit specialization I expected to have the below code. But this gives a compile error.

```
template<>   char* maxAmong(  char* x, const char* y) {
    return x;
}
```

Whereas the making both return type and both arguments const  works

```
template<>  const char* maxAmong( const char* x, const char* y) {
    return x;
}
```

Why does the code in second snippet fail as for me the code looks more right that way.

Comment: `template<>   char* maxAmong(  char* x, char* const y) {` this is constant pointer. You have pointer to constant, this is a difference.

Comment: In the specialisation I was expecting the type T to be char*. So 1st argument and return type to be char* and second argument a const char*( const of type T as in the original template definition).

Comment: The second argument is actually a `char* const` not `const char*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const char *` is a pointer to a `const char`.

`char * const` is a constant pointer to a `char`.

Thus, your template specialization should look like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/jcYTMr8eh):

```
template<typename T>
T maxAmong( T x, const T y) {
    return x ;
}

template<> 
char* maxAmong( char* x,  char* const y) {
    return x;
}
```

This thread might be helpful as well.

[What is the difference between char * const and const char *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char)