# 2 constants in one parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I'm learning C++ from "C++ for Programmers" book. In "templates" section, there is a code like that:

```
template<typename T>
void printArray(const T * const array, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

My question is, the constants of first parameter in function. I have never seen two constants in one parameter. I tried to realize but I could not. Thanks for helps.

Comment: The first `const` means that you won't be allowed to modify the pointed object through that pointer, while the second `const` means that you won't be allowed to modify the pointer itself (e.g. make it point to a different object, set it to `nullptr`, etc.)

Comment: const pointer to type T which is also const?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const T * const` means: a constant pointer to a constant T. Which means that both the pointer and the `T` pointed are constant.

A good rule for reading this kind of parameters is to [read it right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/a/162615/493122).

Comment: I think you reversed it twice.  Once by rearranging in reverse order, and then by reading it right-to-left.  Do one or the other but not both.

Comment: @BenVoigt, yeah, I've that messed up. It's easy to read it in your mind, but hard to put it down in English.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you have a `const` pointer to a `const` object of type `T`. This means you can't change where the pointer is pointing or the object to which it points.

You can actually have const in even more places in a single line. Take this declaration for example:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    const std::string& get_name(const int * const id) const;
};
```

In this case, the function `get_name` is constant, and can't modify the instance of `MyClass`. It takes in a constant pointer to a constant integer, and returns a constant reference to a string.

If you'd like to learn more about best practices while using `const` (and other parts of C++), I highly recommend Bruce Eckel's book [Effective C++: 55 Specific Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876).

Comment: `T` is not necessary an object.

Comment: @Jeffrey I don't think it can be a function or reference, so how can `T` not be the type of an object?

Comment: @Jeffrey An object can be a scalar type too.

Comment: @Rapptz, but a scalar type is not necessary an object.

Comment: @Jeffrey In the Standard, "object" is just a region of storage with some properties. E.g. there can be objects of type `int`. In this sense of "object", all "instances" of scalar types are objects.

Comment: @Jeffrey 1.8.1 of the C++11 standard says: An *object* is a
region of storage. So yes, a scalar type is indeed an object since it takes up storage.

Comment: @derekerdmann, not it's not worth a downvote, that's why I undid it.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax just tells you that there is a pointer that is const and the thing it points to is also const.

For more reading I would recommend you have a look at:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-ptr-vs-ptr-const.html

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-correctness.html