# C++98 curly brace const scalar initialization

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++98

I stumbled upon the code which I do not understand. Here's a simplified version of it:

```
template <int> struct A {};

int const i = { 42 };
typedef A<i> Ai;

int const j = 42;
typedef A<j> Aj;
```

This code compiles with GCC in C++98 mode, but not in Clang. Clang produces the following error:

```
$ clang -Wall -Wextra -std=c++98 -c test.cpp

test.cpp:4:11: error: non-type template argument of type 'int' is not an integral constant expression
typedef A<i> Ai;
          ^
test.cpp:4:11: note: initializer of 'i' is not a constant expression
test.cpp:3:11: note: declared here
int const i = { 42 };
          ^
```

As far as I understand initialization of `int` with and without curly braces should be equivalent. Clang initializes `i` correctly to `42`, just doesn't think it's a compile time constant.

This code compiles well in C++11 mode.

Is there a reason `j` is treated as a compile time constant and `i` is not? Or is it simply a bug in Clang?

**Update:** I opened a [ticket](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18283) in LLVM bug tracker with this issue.

Comment: i would say it's a bug in the compiler.

Comment: @Raxvan: That's quite a bold statement... Considering it works in C++11 and not in C++98 it seems pretty deliberate, so I would actually expect it to be *as per specs* (on Clang part), and gcc being more lenient as usual.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I think that this is what he wanted to tell: its a bug in gcc. There is no C++98 syntax for this, and clang rightfully rejects it. So accepting it in gcc, despite not being C++98, is a bug.

Comment: i'm checking the 98 standard right now to find all the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler error states that `"template argument of type 'int' is not an integral constant expression"` for `int const i = { 42 };`

According to [98 standard](http://sites.cs.queensu.ca/gradresources/stuff/cpp98.pdf) the template argument should fall into this category:

> 14.3.2 / 1
>
> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of:
>
> - an **integral constant-expression** of integral or enumeration type; or
>
> ...

and the definition of integral constant expression `int const i` fall into this category:

> 5.19 Constant expressions
>
> An integral constant-expression can involve only literals (2.13), enumerators, **const variables** or static
>   data members

and for the initialization of `i` (like Mike Seymour post):

> 8.5 Initializers /13
>
> If T is a scalar type, then a declaration of the form
>
> T x = { a };
>
> is equivalent to
>
> T x = a;

Now based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162480/const-int-vs-int-const-as-function-parameter-in-c-and-c) the declaration of `const int` and `int const` should be the same (could not find this specifically in standard) making `i` a **const variable**. So any usage of `i` should be an integral constant expression regardless of the initialization method. It appears there is a bug in clang. Checking the web i could not find a bug report only two more or less similar:

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=666539

and

http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmbugs/2011-March/017353.html

Answer (score 6):

Yes, both declarations are equivalent, per C++98 8.5/13:

> If `T` is a scalar type, then a declaration of the form

```
T x = { a };
```

> is equivalent to

```
T x = a;
```

So both variables are constant, and initialised from a constant expression, so (as far as I can see) should both be usable as constant expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Clang is right. initializer list is not an expression. There is a difference between initialization of aggregate objects and fundamental objects. When a POD object is initialized then each initializer can be considered as a const expression. However when you deal with fundamental types then initializer list is not an expression and is not a const expression.

In paragraph #14 of the Standard there is written:

> *The source type is not defined when the initializer is brace-enclosed*
>   or when it is a parenthesized list of expressions