# what is the difference between `const int *t` and `int const * t`?

Tags: c, constants

I know the difference between these two:

- pointers that do not allow modifications to the data, declared 
  like so `const int *pnPtr = &nValue;`
- pointers that must always point to the same address, declared like 
  so `int *const pnPtr = &nValue;`

but what about this:

- `const int *t`
- `int const * t`

Comment: here you have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162480/const-int-vs-int-const-as-function-parameter-in-c-and-c It's the same

Comment: IIRC, they are the same type.