# Are there any downsides to marking all variables you don't modify const?

Tags: c++, refactoring, constants

After much googling I've found a lot about marking functions and their parameters as `const`, but no guide on marking variables as `const`.

Here's a really simple example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void example(const std::string& x) {
  size_t length = x.length();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    std::cout << x.at(i) << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  example("hello");
}
```

Why not make

```
size_t length = x.length();
```

const like

```
const size_t length = x.length();
```

by convention?

I know such a small, simple example really doesn't show any huge benefit to this, but it seems like it'd be helpful in a larger codebase where you might accidentally mutate a variable you shouldn't have mutated.

Despite that benefit, I don't really see it used that much (in the C++ codebases I've seen) or mentioned nearly as much as making functions and their parameters `const`.

Is there some downside to doing this other than having to type 5 extra characters? I haven't found much on the topic, and I don't want to shoot myself in the foot if it's a problem having so many consts.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I'm concerned it might be too subjective for this site. (Personally, I say go for it!)

Comment: I tend to code like this, but remember that this _might_ become stack-intensive (i.e., you don't reuse temporaries then).

Comment: Making variables which do not change constant is a good habit to improve readability of code. However, people get lazy too soon.

Comment: "*const is your friend: Immutable values are easier to understand, track, and reason about, so prefer constants over variables wherever it is sensible and make const your default choice when you define a value* " -- "C++ Coding Standards", Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu.

Comment: "The reason that const works in C++ is because you can cast it away. If you couldn't cast it away, then your world would suck." - Anders Hejlsberg

Comment: SO is funny. 2 weeks ago I asked a question why the modern C++ compiler do not use the highest warning level and the question got closed and down voted...

Comment: I think the main downsides are that you have to remember to write `const` everywhere, and it clutters your code when you read it later.

Comment: You can not make functions const. That is only possible for member fuctions. Usually you do not make parameter const.  It is only done for pointer and references because you otherwise could change values outside the function.

Comment: good question, because it focuses on **variables** and therefore how to structure code...

Comment: Absolutely: it litters your code and limits your implementations and is hard to maintain and is a bad practice. It's like crying wolf: eventually you become numb to seeing const everywhere and start ignoring it because most of the time it's an insignificant usage of it without real value or meaning. Related: [Use of 'const' for function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117293/use-of-const-for-function-parameters/60823004#60823004).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There are no downsides to marking variables you don't modify `const`.

There are some up-sides though: the compiler will help you diagnose when you unintentionally modify a variable you shouldn't/didn't mean to and the compiler *may* (although due to the language having `const_cast` and `mutable` this is rare) generate better code.

So, I'd advise; use `const` where you can. There are no downsides and your compiler can potentially help you spot bugs. No reason not to (except for a bit of extra typing).

Note that this extends to member functions as well. Make them `const` when you can - it lets them be used in more contexts and helps users reason about the code ("calling this function won't modify the object" is valuable information).

Comment: Note that, when some temp var is const, another programmer usually won't reuse it (removing const) but introduce a new const. _Usually_ that's acceptable (and even the right thing), but it might become too stack-intensive for e.g. deeply recursive functions.

Comment: Over verbosity is a downside. It can definitely make the code less readable and harder to maintain. In OP's code piece, for example, making *length* *const* doesn't add real value. Yes, it will protect the variable from unintended modification. On the other hand, if it's modified, the code probably has much deeper problems than accidental typo. That is in contrast to the *x* which is part of the API and making it *const* is an essential and important part of the contract compliance that the function requires from its users.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Never underestimate the ability of some junior maintenance programmer refactoring your code in the future and not paying attention to the fact that some variable was not intended to be modified, to accidentally introduce bugs - using `const` wherever you can helps stopping those people introducing bugs. I've seen it happen in real life more times than I wish I had..

Comment: True. But such errors are pretty rare and should be pretty easily discovered. On the other side the impact of "consting" is overall on the entire code base and on all the people working on it.. To emphasize - I'm referring mostly to the trivial cases such as the piece of code here

Comment: I don't think `const_cast` hinders optimisation that much : if the *value* has been declared `const`, trying to cast it away is UB.

Comment: On the subject of "no downsides", if the variable has a class type and at some point in the future you decide to `std::move` from it, `const` will cause the copy constructor to be silently invoked instead of the move constructor if these constructors are declared in the usual way - taking `const A&` and `A&&`, respectively.

Comment: To reinforce this: some new languages (I'm thinking of Swift and Scala) have marking unchanged variables "constant" a convention. With Swift you have `let` and with Scala you have `val`, and both of these are like the C++ code `const auto`

Comment: @bogdan If you've actively marked a variable as const, you should understand that it means the object is non-mutable, regardless of the method you use to change it, either explicit or implicit (such as via move semantics). In this case it's a bug rather than downside, IMHO.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Of course it's a bug. The downside is that in this case `const` will cause a *silent* bug, rather than a diagnostic. It's basically a (corner) case where `const` hinders rather than helps.

Comment: In modern C++, with move semantics, there are a few situations where declaring a local variable `const` that you then return, will prevent the compiler from generating an automatic move. So be aware of that - clang-tidy has a check to catch those situations, which is helpful.

Answer (score 22):

I can think of at least two downsides:

- verbosity: more words, more symbols to process, ...
- inertia: if you need to modify it, you'll have to go and remove this `const`

and both are worth it.

---

Verbosity is an often heard argument against explicitness, however people often mistake reading speed with understanding speed. There is a balance to be found between verbosity and explicitness, certainly, too verbose may drown out useful information but too implicit/terse may not present information that has to be reconstructed/inferred/deduced/.

Personally, I use a strongly typed statically checked language so that the compiler picks out my mistake as early as possible; annotating with `const` is both giving information to the reader *and* the compiler. I judge it worth the extra 6 symbols.

As for inertia, removing `const` is probably only a small cost of the change... and it repays itself by forcing you to go through all the places where it's used and review the surrounding code to ensure it's actually alright to remove this `const`. Suddenly modifying a particular piece of data in a code path where it previously was immutable requires ensuring that no part of the code path (or its callers) accidentally relied on this immutability.

Comment: As the code changes, it's far easier to remove `const` later, if it turns out that you didn't need it, than it is to add it if it turns out you really should have been clear about the constness.  In my mind, the `const` on a simple declaration is a small cost to pay for the information it conveys to the reader.  When `const` is there, I know that the temporary was created just to give a meaningful name to an expression and not because it's a property that's going to change over time and perhaps have to abide by some non-obvious invariants.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Totally agree.

Comment: I think the inertia argument is important.  While everyone says "its easy to remove the `const`," and they're right, you do run the risk of making it easier to do other solutions, like copying the value into a new variable.  I wouldn't do it when deadlines are nice, but in that last 2 hours before a release when the code still isn't working, little hacks like that are surprisingly easy to make.  In fact, just today I had to do that to an argument (not a local).  The argument was const in the interface, but it didn't need to be.  I didn't have time to fix the interface, so copy it is!

Comment: @CortAmmon: If you can afford the copy performance-wise, I would argue that copying is better because any change to the local is... local. No need to worry about far-ranging effects or anything. From a maintenance perspective, this guarantee of being side-effect free wrt. this argument is a nice property. Also, specifically to your anecdote, if it had not been annotated `const` and you had modified it... how confident would you be that you didn't accidentally break something? If you don't have time to check where it's used to guarantee they're not relying on the argument being immutable...

Comment: @MatthieuM. True, if all code was written perfectly, we'd only write perfect code =)  The issue however, is that now the code still has inertia, and it is less perfect than before.  Now a second tweak could create even more complexity that wasn't needed.  If you have an unlimited refactor budget, this doesn't matter.  However, when you're balancing refactoring against the other budgetary pressures, it's easy to get into situations where there isn't quite enough energy to fix the code, so instead we make it worse.  I hate code that develops inertia because it has inertia.

Comment: I've been given the privileged of refactoring entire modules, and cutting the SLOC count down by 90% because almost all of the code in that module was hacks working around the inertia caused by the previous hack.  It's very easy to double down on a bad assumption, rather than fixing it.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of this ¹non-standard code:

```
#import <string>
#import <iostream>

void example(const std::string& x) {
  size_t length = x.length();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    std::cout << x.at(i) << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  example("hello");
}
```

… I'd write this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void example( string const& s )
{
    for( char const ch : s )
    {
        cout << ch << '\n';
    }
}

auto main()
    -> int
{ example( "hello" ); }
```

The main place I could add `const`, relative to the original code, was for the `ch` variable in the loop. I think that's nice. `const` is generally desirable because it reduces the possible code actions one has to consider, and range based loops let you have more `const`.

The main drawback of using `const` for most things, is when you have to relate to C APIs.

Then one just has to make some gut feeling decisions about whether to copy data, or trust in the documentation and use a `const_cast`.

---

*Addendum 1:*
Do note that `const` on a return type prevents move semantics.  As far as I know this was first noted by Andrei Alexandrescu in his [Mojo (C++03 move semantics) article](http://www.drdobbs.com/move-constructors/184403855) in Dr Dobbs Journal:

> **”** [A] `const` temporary looks like an oxymoron, a contradiction in terms. Seen from a practical perspective, `const` temporaries force copying at destination.

So, this is one place where one should *not* use `const`.

Sorry that I forgot to mention this originally; I was reminded by [user bogdan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38925121/are-there-any-downsides-to-marking-all-variables-you-dont-modify-const/38925315?noredirect=1#comment65209185_38925200) on another answer.

---

*Addendum 2:*
In the same vein (to support move semantics), if the last thing done with a formal argument is to store a copy somewhere, then instead of passing by reference to `const` it can be better to use a non-`const` argument passed by value, because it can be simply moved from.

I.e., instead of

```
string stored_value;

void foo( string const& s )
{
    some_action( s );
    stored_value = s;
}
```

… or the redundancy of optimized

```
string stored_value;

void foo( string const& s )
{
    some_action( s );
    stored_value = s;
}

void foo( string&& s )
{
    some_action( s );
    stored_value = move( s );
}
```

… consider just writing

```
string stored_value;

void foo( string s )
{
    some_action( s );
    stored_value = move( s );
}
```

It can be slightly less efficient for the case of lvalue actual argument, it discards the advantages of `const` (constraints on what the code could possibly do), and it breaks a uniform convention of using `const` wherever possible, but it doesn't perform badly in any situation (which is the main goal, to avoid that) and it's smaller and possibly more clear code.

---

<sup>*Notes*:

¹ Standard C++ does not have an `#import` directive. Also, those headers, when properly included, are not guaranteed to define `size_t` in the global namespace.</sup>

Comment: Generally I'd make the variable in a range-for-loop a `const &`. For some types it doesn't matter, for some types it avoids an expensive copy. So unless you explicitly *want/need* a cooy, `const &` seems the sane default..

Comment: Quick question...according to this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/162615/3772221), wouldn't you be able to modify that string? Reading `string const&` right to left it's a constant reference to a mutable string. Sorry to bikeshed...just curious haha.

Comment: @AR7 const applies to the left unless there's no left, in which case it applies to the right. `const string&` is the same as `string const&`. +References are always const (unlike pointers where it may make sense to say `something* const` == an immutable pointer to something mutable).

Comment: Making *const* of a variable that represents a **copy** is pretty meaningless in most cases. +1 to @JesperJuhl  approach

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername I don't see why? You are going to use that copy and you don't want it to be modified before it gets used.

Comment: @JesperJuhl But in this case a `const&` would likely slow the loop down. Copying a single `char` is likely to be rather faster than dereferencing.

Comment: @Galik Consider the scope. The actual data that you care about is safe (in *s* in this example).

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Only in this trivial example. If it were a math calculation with a bunch of variables you want to make sure the non-changing ones don't change.

Comment: @Galik Maybe so. On the other hand, in such case code refactoring might be a better approach.

Comment: Is no one going to point out the pointlessness of a trailing return type on (what should be by convention) `int main()` or the use of `using namespace std` in the "preferred" method?

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Code refactoring should be done because the code needs refactoring not to avoid using `const`. What I mean is that code refactoring is orthogonal to whether or not a variable that is not supposed to change should be marked `const`.

Comment: @Galik I meant that if the code is written in a way that local temporary variables should be protected from modifying, such code should probably be refactored in a first place, regardless of consting.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername I suppose I just don't know of a way to write code such that local variables that should not be modified won't benefit from being marked `const`.

Comment: @Galik Rewrite it with several functions

Comment: I updated the answer after being reminded of return values by a comment elsewhere. Is there more I've forgotten to mention?

Comment: Where's the standard violation in the first snippet?

Comment: @user2357112: E.g., standard C++ does not have an `#import` directive. Also, those headers, when properly included, are not guaranteed to define `size_t` in the global namespace.

Comment: @JonHarper: Good conventions are not pointless; you could have asked instead of asserted (and misleading others). `using namespace std;` is perfectly fine in a short example or beginner's program; ditto. The quotes around "preferred" in your comment seems to indicate that you're happy with the non-standard original code, that's surprising.

Comment: I did not assert that good conventions are pointless, I asserted that your *not following* a good convention is pointless (at best, counterproductive at worst). The UNS argument is a dead horse; I'll leave our disagreement where it is. The "preferred" is a disambiguation to simplify what I could have called "the code you wrote".

Comment: @JonHarper: Sounds like social issues to me. Good luck.

Comment: "auto main() -> int" - really?

Comment: @immibis: It's the modern syntax, from C++11 (we're now at C++14, with C++17 coming up). It's better in most ways than the old C++03 syntax, and some functions can't be expressed in the old syntax. You have some serious catching up to do, but it'll be fun. :-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I know what the syntax means, there's just no reason to use it here.

Comment: @immibis: I use it as a single convention, and it is a good convention. As I see it there is no reason to use both syntaxes except for legacy code. If you think about it, there's something silly about mingling two different syntaxes, where one of them is so limited it can't be used in all cases, and where also that syntax has a bunch of problems. I decided long ago to not mislead newbies by using that no-advantage-many-disadvantages silliness in SO answers. What to do in a project with old project guidelines, is something else. Arguments to the contrary have all so far been social. Conformism.

Comment: Though note that main is special case anyway, its specialness defined in the standard, and pretty much dictated by legacy reasons. So having different syntax for main can be seen as intentionally indicating it is special.

Comment: To follow up on @hyde, consider searching for "int main" and getting no results...

Answer (score 5):

For the local variable `size_t length` in a short method like this it doesn't really matter. The downside of extra verbosity basically balances with the relative safety of avoiding typos accidentally modifying the length. Do whatever your local style guide, or your own gut feeling tells you.

For a longer or more complex method, it might be different. But then again, if you have so complex a method that it matters, maybe you should at least consider refactoring your code to simpler pieces... Anyway, if you read and understand the code, extra hint provided by explicit `const` is kinda irrelevant - nice but irrelevant.

---

Slightly related, though you didn't ask about it: For the reference parameter of your `example` method, you definitely do want `const`, because you might need to pass it a const string. Only if you want to disable passing const string (because you think you'll add code to modify it), you should omit `const` there.

Answer (score 3):

> I know such a small, simple example really doesn't show any huge
>   benefit to this, but it seems like it'd be helpful in a larger
>   codebase where you might accidentally mutate a variable you shouldn't
>   have mutated.

The problem is that this basically never actually happens.

On the other hand, `const` is a disease that *will* spread through your codebase like a plague. As soon as you declare a `const` variable, all the things you need on it must be `const`, and so they must only call `const` functions, and it just never stops.

`const` isn't remotely worth the price you pay for it in the infinite majority of situations. There's only a couple of cases where `const` actually protects you (e.g. set keys), but even then, it's debatable if you'd have to be a total moron to try that in the first place, and probably not worth all the language rules and incessant code duplication and redundant metalogic.

`const` is a nice idea that might be nice in theory, but the practical realities are that `const` is a total waste of time and space. Burn it with fire.

Comment: This was what I was looking for haha. Do you have any examples you've run into personally?

Comment: Just use Rust, then you don't need to write `const`. ;-)

Comment: I wanted to use a pointer as a key in an `unordered_map`, then call some functions on it which are all non-mutating, but then I had to mark them all as const, and ...

Comment: `but the practical realities are that const is a total waste of time and space. Burn it with fire.` Hm, as of my experience at least, I encountered more bugs by far due to unintended modifications than I had issues due to inflated const-usage. It's right, const at least at interface level, is a design element and should be used like every design element and aspect: with reason.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with most of the answers given so far, on the other hand, some aspects are still missing.

When defining interfaces, the `const` keyword is your friend. But you should know that it's also somewhat limited and sometimes even egoistic - this is what I'd call its downsides.

Let's have another *close look* on the question:

> Are there any downsides to marking all variables you don't modify const?`

If you *observe* that ***you don't modify*** something, you may say that it's effectively a constant. Also code analysis tools can detect this, even your compiler will already know it. But this observation should not trigger an *add-const reflex* in you.

Instead think about the variable itself, ask

- Is it useful at all?
- Is it also intended to be constant?

Sometimes an intermediate variable can simply be removed, sometimes a small rework (adding or removing a function) can be done to improve the code.

Adding the `const` keyword may harden your code against errors elsewhere, but also against changes at the declaration point.

Let me also add a word about member variables that don't change. If you decide to declare a member variable `const`, you have to initialize it in the initializer list of the constructor of the containing class, this extends the preconditions for constructing objects of this class.

So don't add `const` wherever your compiler allows for it. Do not be seduced to "petrify your code" ;-)